# Find variants without sub-queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I work with a very meta system that allows user to define their own form and reports... think sharepoint lists or wordpress, but more market specific.

In this specific case "Collection,Row" key sets should always have a single distinct table_id to a single distinct folder_id, and we found a case where some invalid data got through and I used the query below to check for the problem.

I am curious if there is a way to produce the results without using sub-queries.

This is just an educational/theory question, but eventually I may need to implement a check constraint to prevent these variants and performance may come into play.

```sql
/* Only one Database table per collection set */
SELECT
    ic.folder_id "Folder #"
  , ic.table_id "Table #"
  , LISTAGG(ic.column_id
  , ',') WITHIN GROUP(
    ORDER BY
        ic.folder_id
      , ic.table_id
    ) "Columns"
FROM
    cols ic
WHERE
    ic.folder_id IN (
        SELECT
            ic02.folder_id
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    ic01.folder_id
                  , ic01.table_id
                FROM
                    cols ic01
                WHERE
                    v.key_set = 'Collection,Row'
                GROUP BY
                    folder_id
                  , table_id
            ) ic02
        GROUP BY
            ic02.folder_id
        HAVING
            COUNT(0) > 1
    )
GROUP BY
    ic.folder_id
  , ic.table_id;
```

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='8859_9' ?>
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="Folder_#">315</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="Table_#">2141</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="Variables">4397,4398,4399,4400,4401,4402,4403,4404,4405,4406,4407,4408,4409,4410,4411,4412</COLUMN>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="Folder_#">315</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="Table_#">9020</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="Variables">10924,10926,10934,10935</COLUMN>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="Folder_#">316</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="Table_#">2142</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="Variables">4413,4414,4415,4416,4417,4418,4419</COLUMN>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="Folder_#">316</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="Table_#">9021</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="Variables">10943,10945,10949,10953,10954</COLUMN>
    </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this would give the same results -

```
SELECT
    ic.folder_id "Folder #"
  , ic.table_id "Table #"
  , LISTAGG(ic.column_id
  , ',') WITHIN GROUP(
    ORDER BY
        ic.folder_id
      , ic.table_id
    ) "Columns"
FROM
    cols ic
WHERE key_set = 'Collection,Row'
GROUP BY
    ic.folder_id
  , ic.table_id
HAVING
    COUNT(0) > 1
```